# Is it possible to create IS-A relationship in Java without extending the class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am a newbie to Java and wondering if it is possible to create IS-A relationship in Java without extending the class. i.e Is there any other way to create IS-A relationship in Java other than extending the class?

Comment: you can implement an interface too

Comment: It will be helpful if you can mention in what context you are asking this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Java, is-a relation between the type parameters of one class or interface and the type parameters of another are determined by the extends and implements clauses.

You can refer wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a#Java) here for more information.

> IS-A is a way of saying : This object is a type of that object.

Reference: [Tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm)

The IS-A relationship can be achieved by either using extends keyword and extending a class or by implementing an interface.

Comment: so does it means that we cannot create a IS-A relationship other than, extending and implementing?

Comment: In java as far as I know it is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you to make use of **Interface** and implement a class to achieve this.

Comment: If you make it an answer, Please also explain the differences and benefits of interfaces. :)

Comment: This looks like an answer but I'm left thinking, "Why is this correct?" I don't know because you didn't explain anything.